# Change docker log messages location

Tags: linux, logging, docker

I met a problem with docker logging and after reading a lot of sources didn't find solution: is there a way to discard messages of docker daemon in `/var/log/messages` and select another location?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I know that this question is quite old but I don't think it has been answered well and no correct answer has been stated.

First of all the reason why it saves messages to that particular place starts in rsyslog configuration (`/etc/rsyslog.conf`) with the line:

```
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
```

So, because docker saves information to systemd journal it ends at `/var/log/messages`.

To be able to save it to other places, you have to create a rule like the following at `/etc/rsyslog.d/docker.conf`.

```
$FileCreateMode 0644
template(name="DockerLogFileName" type="list") {
   constant(value="/var/log/docker/")
   property(name="syslogtag" securepath="replace" \
            regex.expression="docker/\\(.*\\)\\[" regex.submatch="1")
   constant(value="/docker.log")
}
if $programname == 'dockerd' then \
  /var/log/docker/combined.log
if $programname == 'dockerd' then \
  if $syslogtag contains 'docker/' then \
    ?DockerLogFileName
  else
    /var/log/docker/no_tag/docker.log
$FileCreateMode 0600
```

I found the information for this configuration here:
https://www.simulmedia.com/blog/2016/02/19/centralized-docker-logging-with-rsyslog/

Answer (score 2):

Configure rsyslog to isolate the Docker logs into their own file. To do this create /etc/rsyslog.d/10-docker.conf and copy the following content into the file.

```
# Docker logging
daemon.* {
 /var/mylog
 stop
}
```

In summary this will write all logs for the daemon category to /var/mylog then stop processing that log entry so it isn’t written to the systems default syslog file.

Comment: This is a copy-paste answer. Why didn't you post a link to the [original article](https://www.wolfe.id.au/2015/05/03/syslog-logging-driver-for-docker/)?

Comment: it doesn't isolate docker logs in its own file, it isolates all daemon logs into its own file

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#configure-the-default-logging-driver), you can specify a different driver either as a command-line argument for the docker daemon or (preferably) in the `daemon.json` config file. Several drivers are available, e.g. for Syslog, HTTP-based logging, ...

**Update**

Here's an example configuration section for Syslog (from the documentation):

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts":  {
    "syslog": "udp://1.2.3.4:1111"
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about `dockerd`

Comment: @VyacheslavShvets That's why I mentioned providing a command-line argument for the Docker *daemon* . Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: These options [are default options for containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), not for `dockerd` itself

Comment: @VyacheslavShvets After re-reading the docs, I guess you're right; this will indeed only affect the container's logs, not the daemon's logs.